# How to append variables in nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, nested-lists

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        a=[]
        a.append([name][score])
    print(a)
```

This is error occurred when I insert values

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Nested Lists.py", line 6, in <module>
    a.append([name][score])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Comment: What is your expected resulting `a`?

Comment: If you are trying to append score in a nested list then you need a second for loop. If not, then consider to use a dictionary so you have the name and its score

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `[name][score]`? Maybe you mean `[name, score]`?

Comment: You shouldn't re-initialize `a` inside the loop. Initialize it before the loop, and append to it inside the loop.

Comment: I want to get values in nested list like this,
    [['Prakash',70.60],['Shelar',60.20]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to make a list containing `name` and `score` is `[name, score]`. `[name][score]` means to create a list containing just `[name]`, and then use `score` as an index into that list; this doesn't work because `score` is a `float`, and list indexes have to be `int`.

You also need to initialize the outer list only once. Putting `a=[]` inside the loop overwrites the items that you appended on previous iterations.

```
a=[]
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    a.append([name, score])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary instead of a list (a list will work, but for what you are doing a hashmap is better suited):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores = dict()
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        scores[name] = score
    print(scores)
```

Comment: Based on the name of the file, I think he's doing an exercise to learn about nested lists. A dictionary might be the right solution for a real problem, but not for this.

Answer (score 0):

As others have told, a dictionary is probably the best solution for this case.

However, if you want to add an element with multiple values to a list, you have to create a sublist `a.append([name, score])` or a tuple `a.append((name, score))`.

Keep in mind that tuples can't be modified, so if you want, for instance, to update the score of a user, you must remove the corresponding tuple from the list and add a new one.

In case you just want to add new values to a flat list, simply go for `a = a + [name, score]`. This will add both `name` and `score` to the end of the list as entirely independent elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
deva=[]
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    l=[]
    l.append(name)
    l.append(score)
    deva.append(l)
print(deva)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements the other answers.